# Why does `zip_view` not support `output_range`?

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

I noticed that C++23's [`zip_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view) has the following constraints:

```
template<input_range... Views>
  requires (view<Views> && ...) && (sizeof...(Views) > 0)
class zip_view;
```

which implies that `zip_view` can *only* zip input ranges.

I'm wonder why it excludes `output_range`, since supporting `output_range` can be useful in my opinion. For example, I can zip a bunch of `output_range`s for simultaneous writing, a scenario like:

```
/* zipped input_range */
auto zip_in = views::zip(views::iota(0, 3),
                         views::iota(3, 6),
                         views::iota(6, 9));

std::vector<int> v1, v2, v3;
auto make_insert_range = [](auto inserter) {
  return ranges::subrange(inserter, std::unreachable_sentinel);
};
/* zipped output_range */
auto zip_out = views::zip(make_insert_range(std::back_inserter(v1)),
                          make_insert_range(std::back_inserter(v2)),
                          make_insert_range(std::back_inserter(v3)));

/* copy */
ranges::copy(zip_in, zip_out.begin());
std::println("v1: {}", v1); // v1: [0, 1, 2]
std::println("v2: {}", v2); // v2: [3, 4, 5]
std::println("v3: {}", v3); // v3: [6, 7, 8]
```

Although `zip_out` is currently rejected by the compiler because the constraints are not satisfied.

I believe it is technically feasible to do so. Although this may bring up some thorny issues, such as if a zip `input_range` and `output_range` at the same time, what category of its iterator would be? I think we can just not provide `iterator_concept` and let `zip_view` be an <del>`input_`</del>`range`.

Since I did not find any discussion about supporting `output_range` in the original paper [P2321](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2321r2.html) and range/v3, I want to know why `zip_view` does not support output range from the first place? Is this an unreasonable option?

Comment: tag **language-lawyer**.

Comment: The result category dhould be the most restrictive of all, which would be `ouput_range` if there exists one otherwise `input_iterator` if there exists one...

Comment: No input range adaptor supports output ranges, why should `zip` be any different? We barely even have algorithms that take output ranges - we don't have `ranges::copy(input_range, output_range)`, we only have `iota`, `fill`, and `generate`.

Comment: @Barry I mean, why is `zip_view` an *input* range adaptor in the first place, instead of a more generic *range* adaptor that supports output range like `take_view`, `drop_view` and `common_view`? What stopped zip_iterator from wrapping `input_or_output_iterator`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 I suppose `zip` maybe can just work without any other constraint changes, but adapting output ranges is just a fundamentally different operation for adapting input ranges. You'd want `transform` on an output range would want to `*out++ = f(x);`... not `f(*out++) = x;`

Comment: @Barry That's why (`zip_`)`transform_view` requires input range, isn't it?